# How to convert a HashMap to a TreeMap using a comparator?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

In my code I have the following `HashMap`, where the `key` is a Kennel object and the `value` is a list of Dog objects in that kennel.

When I have populated my `HashMap`, can I then convert it to a `Treemap` and pass in a comparator?

```
Map<Kennel, List<Dog>> mapOfKennelsAndDogs;

//populate the map

//convert it to a treemap?
```

Comment: Well, you already mentioned the things you need. Why do you need us to **try** to make the next step? In other words: your question sounds almost rhetoric; do you really need other people to answer that?

Comment: There's no point in populating one and then converting to the other. Just populate the TreeMap and don't use the HashMap at all

Comment: `treeMap.putAll(hashMap);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the treemap with the comparator, and then add all the entries.

```
Comparator<Kennel> ordering = ...;
TreeMap<Kennel, List<Dog>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(ordering);
treeMap.putAll(mapOfKennelsAndDogs);
```

Comment: Thanks, will this then re-order the hashmap using the comparator?

Comment: No, it will create a new TreeMap with given comparator for ordering the entries. A HashMap can never be ordered by a comparator; it's two fundamentally different implementations of maps.